# Increment all users that enrolled in a list

Tags: development, web-part, user-profile-service

Good day,

I need to add all the users that added and item in list  and save them to another list in one field on my list and retain the information for later reporting using C#.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use workflow for adding users to another list.
Suppose you have List A and List B. You want to add users who created items in A to B. Then attach a workflow on A, so when an item is created on A it will take created by field and make an entry to B. Later on you can write C# code to generate report.